# Multiple counts in hive query not giving expected results

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have data as follows.

[image]

I am trying to get the following results with the query what I have developed.

```
select date,name,act_cd,type_cd, type 
count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (1) THEN key_id ELSE 0 END) as count-of-AB,
count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (2) THEN key_id ELSE 0 END) as count-of-CD
FROM table 
where act_cd in (1,2)
and type in (MR,LP)
group by date,name,act_cd,type_cd,type
```

**Expected Results**

[image]

But its giving following results. Not sure what is the wrong with the query and could soneone let me know how can we get expected results.

**Actual Results**

[image]

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks,Babu

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `ELSE`:

```
select date, name, type_cd, type 
       count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (1) THEN key_id END) as count_of_AB,
       count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (2) THEN key_id END) as count_of_CD
from table 
where act_cd in (1, 2) and
      type in ('MR','LP')
group by date, name, type_cd, type;
```

The issue with your code is that the `0` counts as a value for `count(distinct)`.

In addition, it is not appropriate to have `act_cd` in the `group by`.

If `key_id` is guaranteed to be unique (at least within a group), then don't use `distinct`.  I prefer `sum()` but you can also use `count()`:

```
select date, name, type_cd, type 
       count(CASE WHEN act_cd in (1) THEN key_id END) as count_of_AB,
       count(CASE WHEN act_cd in (2) THEN key_id END) as count_of_CD
from table 
where act_cd in (1, 2) and
      type in ('MR','LP')
group by date, name, type_cd, type;
```

Answer (score 0):

just a minor bug otherwise your query is ok, you need to pass null in else to not count it :

```
select date,name,act_cd,type_cd, type 
count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as count-of-AB,
count(distinct CASE WHEN act_cd in (2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as count-of-CD
FROM table 
where act_cd in (1,2)
and type in (MR,LP)
group by date,name,act_cd,type_cd,type
```